# IObservable output emitted before input?

Tags: system.reactive

The program below attempts to print out words with their respective lengths. It erroneously reports that cat has 6 letters. As I examine the log, it looks like the length of a specific word is emitted BEFORE the word it is based upon is emitted. How is this possible? The `length` observable is defined as `word.select(i=>i.Length)` so I don't see how it could produce a result before the word arrives. At first I thought this might be a bug in my logging code, but the behavior of `Observable.WithLatestFrom` reinforces my belief that something weird is going on here.

Log results:

```
0001report.Subscribe()
0002first.Subscribe()
0003second.Subscribe()
0002first.OnNext(3)
0003second.OnNext(cat)
0002first.OnNext(6)
0001report.OnNext({ Word = cat, Length = 6 })
0003second.OnNext(donkey)
```

The program:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    ILogger logger = new DelegateLogger(Console.WriteLine);
    Subject<string> word = new Subject<string>();
    IObservable<int> length = word.Select(i => i.Length);
    var report = Observable
        .WithLatestFrom(
            length.Log(logger, "first"),
            word.Log(logger, "second"),
            (l, w) => new { Word = w, Length = l })
        .Log(logger,"report");
    report.Subscribe();
    word.OnNext("cat");
    word.OnNext("donkey");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string input);
}

public class DelegateLogger : ILogger
{
    Action<string> _printer;

    public DelegateLogger(Action<string> printer) {
        _printer = printer;
    }

    public void Log(string input) => _printer(input);
}

public static class ObservableLoggingExtensions
{
    private static int _index = 0;

    public static IObservable<T> Log<T>(this IObservable<T> source, ILogger logger, string name) {
        return Observable.Create<T>(o => {
            var index = Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);
            var label = $"{index:0000}{name}";
            logger.Log($"{label}.Subscribe()");
            var disposed = Disposable.Create(() => logger.Log($"{label}.Dispose()"));
            var subscription = source
                .Do(
                    x => logger.Log($"{label}.OnNext({x?.ToString() ?? "null"})"),
                    ex => logger.Log($"{label}.OnError({ex})"),
                    () => logger.Log($"{label}.OnCompleted()")
                )
                .Subscribe(o);
            return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, disposed);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367304/confusion-over-behavior-of-publish-refcount?

Comment: It appears you have solutions that you want tweaked as opposed to a problem you want help getting a solution to. My gut feel is that your solutions are using the wrong tools/operators so are flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is going on. There are two subscriptions on word (1. length 2. WithLatestFrom), and one subscription on length (1. WithLatestFrom)

When a word is emitted, a synchronous callback process starts that passes it to the first subscriber (length), which calculates a value, that is passed to its subscriber, WithLatestFrom. Next, WithLatestFrom receives the word that generated the calculated length. So WithLatestFrom receives the length BEFORE the word, not the other way around. That's why the report isn't giving me the results I expected.

Comment: You are right, but why are you continuing to create queries that don't work? You seem to have been at this for days and day. Had you done `word.Zip(length, ...)` this query would work as expected. Or better yet, `word.Select(w => new { Word = w, Length = w.Length })`. You're repeated constructing queries that don't work and posting questions about them. Why?

Comment: I figured it all out. I'm using rx for view models. Input properties, like email address or web URL. Output properties like email is formatted correctly (bool) or URL is available. I wanted to correlate inputs and outputs in a GENERAL way but there is no general solution. WithLatestFrom CAN'T do it for synchronous calculations (like this post), but CAN do it if there is a very slight delay between input and output. Subscription side effects - rx not like pure math. I will usually bind input and output together in my results to avoid the problem. Other times maybe zip, join, but carefully.

Comment: Here's a line from one of my favourite songs that might help - "take me down to concurrency city where green pretty is grass the girls the and are". You're dealing with a framework that allows asynchrony and you want to enforce synchrony. You should either make your queries synchronous or incorporate ways of identifying the results from the associated request.

Comment: very funny. love that.